# Django basic models logic

Tags: django, django-models

Looking for a way to create a model with a lot of tasks, each task is boolean ('Completed', 'Uncompleted'), and also it's own uniqe timestamp.

```
class project(models.Model):
  task1 = models.BooleanField()
  task1date = models.DateTimeField()
[...]
```

It's don't make amy sence to me, since there will be a lot to tasks. Every task has it's own title, the title stay the same for every single project (A list of tasks, if you will), but i need an sperate timestamp for the time the task have completed on the speacific project. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

You make an extra model `Task` with three fields `competed`, `timestamp`, and a `ForeignKey` to `Project`:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='tasks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So here a `Task` will refer to a `Project`. You can make as many `Task`s as you want that you relate to a given `Project`. For example with:

```
Task.objects.create(project=my_project)
```

where `my_project` is a `Project` object.

You can access the set of *related* `Task` objects of a `Project` with:

```
myproject.tasks.all()
```

For more information, see the [*many-to-one relations* section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) of the documentation.

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `Project` instead of <s>`project`</s>.

Comment: Thank you, And then if I'll want to watch every project's tasks from the admin form, and edit or add tasks, will I be able to do so? How can I make it a part of the basic project's form on the admin site, or it is not the right way to do so?

Comment: @Arik: yes, you can use an inlinemodeladmin: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects